# Hi, i am trying to put in a sink in the corner of the bathroom

Tags: geometry

The corner of the room is 90 degrees and the front edge of the counter will be 30 inches out from the corner of these two walls. So a triangle with a 90, two 45 corners and i know the 'diameter' is 30. How long are the sides? There must be a simple? formula for that. Thanks

Comment: hypotenuse ? or some other diameter...

Comment: Why don't you just measure it?

Comment: @Neal Sense of humor well appreciated. A rarity these last times...

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

$30\sqrt 2 \approx 42.4$

Comment: That's it! I was drawing lines on the cardboard further and further out till i was really close to 42 inches

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's indeed a formula. The sides are equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ the diamenter, roughly $21.2$.

Please tell me this is real life question and not an exercise. :)

---

Since we are not aware of your definition of "diameter", the exact value of the sides is not known... It's possible that the exact value is an element of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: Indeed, I'm not sure.

Comment: Wife and i really are working on building a counter top for a bathroom sink, mid century modernish lol. Appreciate everyones help Cheers!

Comment: Happy to see maths serving the people.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing the 30 inch line that you described, I see it splits your triangular counter into two sub-triangles, each of which is 45-45-90. The lengths of the sides of one of the sub-triangles are 30, 30, and $30\sqrt{2}$.

So the answer is $30\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Wow, thanks! ok, so my wife figured out to split it into 2 right angle? triangles giving the one side 30, but we couldn't figure out what to do from there. Thanks for the help! Math is cool!